# Did Tolkien ever specify that Orodruin was a volcano?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

It is incredibly clear that Orodruin (Mount Doom) was a volcano.  It is a mountain with fire inside of it, and it periodically belches forth ash, smoke, and rock.  This is what volcanoes do best (really, it's pretty much the *only* thing they do).

But I'm fairly certain that, in *The Lord of the Rings*, Tolkien refers to it exclusively as a mountain, never as a volcano.  I believe the same is true of *The Silmarillion*.

What about his other works, his letters, his notes (as published in the *History of Middle-earth* and *Unfinished Tales*), etc?  Does he ever call the volcano a volcano, or is it always referred to as a mountain?

Comment: It should be noted that we (English) didn't have a word for volcano until 500 years ago: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=volcano

Comment: Could be tolkien didn't want to introduce a roman god into his work.  He would have named it an Aulecano?

Comment: @HorusKol it should likewise be noted that Tolkien didn't write the Lord of the Rings until ~60 years ago. I'm pretty sure he was acquainted with the term

Comment: true - but Tolkien's English in LotR was arcane even by the standards of the 1930s, to lend a sense of history/epic - for a philologist like Tolkien, volcano could have been as out of place as automobile or galleon in his text

Comment: @childcat15: I think the point is not whether Tolkien knew the word, but whether, in some sense, his characters would.  There seems to be a definite preference in Tolkien's writing for "old" words, coming from, let's say, Middle English or earlier.  As HorusKol says, this is part of how he creates the "epic" tone of the work.

Comment: Irrelevant, but: I've often suspected that the Lonely Mountain is a volcano as well, at least in a metaphorical sense. Being "lonely" in itself is geologically improbable for a non-volcanic peak; and then there's the elemental force that lives deep in its interior and periodically comes out to burn the nearby countryside and town. It even has a diagonal shaft leading to its inner chamber.

Comment: @Nathaniel: "Being 'lonely' in itself is geologically improbable for a non-volcanic peak" -- Ayers Rock, Sugarloaf Mountain, Spitzkoppe and a couple more would like to differ here. ;-)

Comment: @HorusKol While he **didn't** use automobile or galleon, he **did** use the incredibly out-of-place *express train*, so I doubt *volcano* would have ripped his readers from their immersion into Middle-earth

Comment: @BMWurm - fair enough, though that was in Chapter 1, and the tone of the writing is a lot less epic before Shadow of the Past.

Comment: @DevSolar [Tolkien's map of the Lonely Mountain and environs](http://antonysimpson.com/2013/book-review-the-hobbit-by-j-r-r-tolkien-printed-by-the-folio-society/) depicts it with the typical shape of a [stratovolcano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratovolcano).

Comment: @zwol: That's not the point I was argueing. I was argueing that non-volcanic "lonely" mountains do exist. You know, internet is the place where simple misconceptions grow into things "everybody" knows, and I don't like that, so I point them out.

Comment: All: Yes, Old English did not have a word for Volcano, but it's progenitor Nordic languages had ***many*** words for them and LotR was not only inspired by Nordic mythology, Tolkein was a world renowned expert in ancient Nordic languages, literature and mythology.  So if Tolkein had wanted to include words for Volcanoes, he would have had no trouble at all, stylistically, thematically nor linguistically with doing it.

Comment: @HorusKol: Tolkien's English was not 'arcane', then or now.  He just presumed that his audience had a reasonable standard of literacy, rather than writing for the lowest common denominator.   He chose to use words carefully (see "On Translation" in the appendices to LOTR), which IMHO adds considerably to the "willing suspension of disbelief" that makes the book enjoyable.

Comment: @jamesqf - Philologists still debate what Tolkien meant by "Weapontake".  That strongly suggests that he deliberately used archaic words.

Comment: @Wad Cheber: Or coined his own, with a prettty obvious meaning :-)  Even if one accepts 'archaic', that by no means equates to 'arcane'.  He was simply writing for a literate audience.  I certainly had no trouble understanding the language(s) of LOTR when I first read it, in my teens.

Comment: Sorry if you feel "arcane" to be too strong a description - I did not mean to imply incomprehensibility - simply unusual. I agree that LotR is comprehensible, especially as my first reading was at age 10.

Comment: I was actually very disappointed by the movie's portrayal of this grand volcano. In my head when I first read the books, Mt Doom contained an ancient abandoned forge where the fire never died out. Walls covered in molten metal and all. Had Sauron not been a disembodied spirit at that point, this would have been his workplace.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

No, Tolkien never uses the word "volcano" to describe Orodruin.

The closest he comes is "Mountain of Fire", an epithet (note the capitalization) that gets frequently applied to it. In *Fellowship*, for example (emphasis mine):

> Then all listened while Elrond in his clear voice spoke of Sauron and the Rings of Power, and their forging in the Second Age of the world long ago. A part of his tale was known to some there, but the full tale to none, and many eyes were turned to Elrond in fear and wonder as he told of the Elven-smiths of Eregion and their friendship with Moria, and their eagerness for knowledge, by which Sauron ensnared them. For in that time he was not yet evil to behold, and they received his aid and grew mighty in craft, whereas he learned all their secrets, and betrayed them, and **forged secretly in the Mountain of Fire the One Ring** to be their master. But Celebrimbor was aware of him, and hid the Three which he had made; and there was war, and the land was laid waste, and the gate of Moria was shut.
>
> <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 2: "The Council of Elrond"</sub></sup>

In *The Silmarillion* is is also referred to as a "fiery mountain":

> There above the valley of Gorgoroth was built his fortress vast and strong, Barad-dûr, the Dark Tower; and there was a fiery mountain in that land that the Elves named Orodruin.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Silmarillion* V *Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age*</sub></sup>

And in a draft of what would become chapter 2 of *Fellowship*, Orodruin is referred to as a "fire-mountain":

> I can think of only one way: one would have to find the Cracks of Doom in the depths of Orodruin, the Fire-Mountain, and case the Ring in there, if he really wished to destroy it, or put it beyond all reach until the End.
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* VII *The Treason of Isengard* Chapter II "The Fourth Phase (1): From Hobbiton to Bree"</sub></sup>

"Mountain of Fire" is actually a fair translation of "Orodruin", in fact; *The Silmarillion* "Index of Names" translates it as "Mountain of Blazing Fire", and from the Appendix we can see that it's comprised of the words *orod*, "mountain", and *ruin*, "red flame".

The only time I can find where Orodruin is referred to as a "volcano" is in one of Christopher Tolkien's notes:

> No doubt because Gil-galad had by then discovered that Sauron was busy in Eregion, but had secretly begun the making of a stronghold in Mordor (Maybe already an Elvish name for that region, because of its volcano Orodruin and its eruptions - which were not made by Sauron but were a relic of the devastating works of Melkor in the long First Age)
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* XII *The Peoples of Middle-earth*  Part 2 Late Writings Chapter 13 "Last Writings" Note 14</sub></sup>

However, there is one interesting almost-connection. One of the few uses of the word "volcano" by Tolkien occurs in the Notion Club Papers, an abandoned novel which revolves around contemporary Oxford scholars discussing dreams of Númenor:

> 'Still that seems to be where you got your Volcano and Tree from. But you've given them a twist that's not in your source. You've put them in a different order, I think, making the Tree further west; and your Volcano is not a hell-smithy, but apparently a last peak of some Atlantis.
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* IX *Sauron Defeated* Part Two: "The Notion Club Papers" The Notion Club Papers Part Two</sub></sup>

In-context, this description is quite clearly of the Meneltarma, which was believed to remain above water after the drowning of Númenor<sup>1</sup>.

What I found interesting was a note by Christopher Tolkien immediately following the paragraph, where he notes:

> The passage Lowdham refers to is 33-52 [of the poem they are discussing], where when 'the smoking cloud asunder broke' they 'saw that Tower of Doom': in the earliest text of the poem the mariners 'looked upon Mount Doom'.
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* IX *Sauron Defeated* Part Two: "The Notion Club Papers" The Notion Club Papers Part Two. Note 81</sub></sup>

While there's no context where it makes sense for this mountain to be Orodruin, I believe this writing predates Tolkien's work on *Lord of the Rings*, so we can see where he was getting the idea.

---

<sup>1</sup> From *Akallabêth*:

> Among the Exiles many believed that the summit of the Meneltarma, the Pillar of Heaven, was not drowned for ever, but rose again above the waves, a lonely island lost in the great waters
>
> <sup><sub>*The Silmarillion* IV *Akallabêth*</sub></sup>

Comment: Brilliant as always, Jason.  +1

Comment: It seems likely that Tolkien intentionally avoided the word, just like he avoided other words that would be anachronistic or too culturally specific; in other words too out of character for the English medieval fantasy setting.

Comment: *volcano* is also a word of Romance etymology -- another reason Tolkien might have avoided it.

Comment: Just like _mountain of fire_ is a direct translation of _Orodruin_, both of these also directly translate _eldfjall_, which is at least the Modern Icelandic word for a volcano (I haven't been able to confirm whether it is Old Norse as well), so it's possible the name is simply meant to mean _volcano_.

Comment: @PepijnSchmitz Well, he did use words such as "guns" and "golf".

Answer (score 32):

Hobbit Chapter 12: Inside Information Tolkien writes:

> The dwarves were still passing the cup from hand to hand and talking
>   delightedly of the recovery of their treasure, when suddenly a vast
>   rumbling woke in the mountain underneath as if it was an old
>   **volcano** that had made up its mind to start eruptions once again.

This of course isn't referring to Mount Doom, but it's nevertheless a reference to a volcano.

Comment: An interesting reference too, since The Hobbit is written in language more intermediary between the world described and the world of the reader than The Lord of The Rings which is generally closer in language to the characters' understanding. It could suggest that while there were volcanoes in the Third Age, including Mount Doom, those in the north west did not have a term for them.

Comment: Also the metaphors/similes in Tolkien's works aren't necessarily in the same “old-fashioned” tone as the rest.

Comment: In his later writing Tolkien was very sensitive to how the real-life etymology of words affected their appropriateness in his fictional contexts. That's certainly why he dropped the Native American word "tobacco", which appears several times in The Hobbit, and instead used "pipe-weed" in LOTR. It's possible he stopped using the word "volcano" for the same reason – as a Latin-derived word it has associations with modern scientific terminology, which would feel out of place in his world.

Answer (score 12):

Tolkien never calls Orodruin a volcano, but he does mention its eruption in his sketches for LotR:

> The mountain begins to rumble.
>   Bingo flies away [i.e. flees away].
>   Eruption.
>   Mordor vanishes like a dark cloud. Elves are seen riding like lights
>   rolling away a dark cloud.
>   The City of Stone is covered in ashes.

[...]

> Eruption of Fiery Mountain causes destruction of Tower.

[...]

> How are Sam and Frodo saved from the eruption?

[...]

> Eruption. The forces of Mordor flee and Horsemen of Rohan
>   pursue.

[...]

> Frodo and Sam, fighting
>   with the last Nazgul on an island of rock surrounded by the fire of
>   the erupting Mount Doom, are rescued by Gandalf's eagle

[...]

> The Mountain boils and erupts.

[...]

> The mountain begins to erupt and crumble.

From *History of Middle-Earth* series.

This leads me to believe that Tolkien clearly depicted Orodruin as a volcano, even though he'd never used that actual word for it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the true answer is that in LOTR, Tolkien was almost always describing things from the point of view of his characters, using the language they would use - indeed, it's supposed to be "translations" of the original tongues into English.  None of his characters seem to have any knowledge of modern geology*, nor of geography outside the West of Middle Earth, and thus Orodruin is the only active volcano they know of.  So why would they have a general word for this thing, which as far as they know is unique?  Thus Tolkien never uses the word in his "translation" of LOTR.

*OK, Gimli might, but he never discusses it other than WRT the caves behind Helm's Deep.